# Convergence in distribution with $\sqrt{n}$-rate implies convergence in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that $\sqrt{n} X_n \leadsto X$ implies $X_n \xrightarrow{p}0$. I know that if $X_n \leadsto X$ then $X_n = O_p(1)$. So $\sqrt{n}X_n \leadsto X$ implies $X_n = O_p(n^{-1/2})$. Now, convergence in probability is equivalent to $o_p(1)$, so I need $O_p(n^{-1/2}) \Longrightarrow o_p(1)$.

$O_p(n^{-1/2})$ means that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $K(\varepsilon),N(\varepsilon)$ such that
$$P\left(|\sqrt{n}X_n|\geq K\right) \leq \varepsilon, \qquad \forall n \geq N$$
and $o_p(1)$ if for every $\varepsilon>0, \delta>0$ there exists $N$ such that
$$P(|X_n| \geq \delta)<\varepsilon, \qquad \forall n \geq N$$

Now for my proof, let $\varepsilon>0,\delta>0$ be fixed. Then, there exist $K,N$ such that
$$P\left(\left|\frac{X_n}{n^{-1/2}}\right| \geq K \right) = P\left(\left|X_n\right| \geq \frac{K}{\sqrt{n}} \right) \leq \varepsilon, \forall n \geq N.$$
Take $N_0$ large enough so that $K/\sqrt{n} \leq \delta$ for all $n \geq N_0$. Now
$$P\left(\left|X_n\right| \geq \delta\right) \leq P\left(\left|X_n\right| \geq \frac{K}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \leq \varepsilon, \qquad \forall n \geq N_0.$$

First: is my proof right?
Second: if this is so, this also implies that the theorem will hold for $X_n = O_p(n^{\alpha})$
for any $\alpha > 0$?, or this works only with $\sqrt{n}$? Thanks

Comment: Yes this looks good. The same will work if $X_n= O_P(u_n)$ for any deterministic sequence $u_n\to 0$.